# c++ vector push_back not working

Tags: c++, stdvector, push-back

My program crashes here:

```
void TriangleStrip::addTriangle(Triangle t){ 
   cout << t <<endl ;
   instances.push_back(t); // problem here
}
```

instances is:

```
vector<Triangle> instances;
```

I call addTriangle here:

```
TriangleStrip* s;
int c = m.getTrianglesCount();
int i;
Triangle* triangles = m.getTriangles();
for(i=0; i<c; i++){
  s->addTriangle(triangles[i]); 
}
```

cout write me the triangle, but I can't put this to the vector.

What is the problem?

Comment: Where is `TriangleStrip* s;` initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TriangleStrip* s;` declares an **uninitialized** pointer, and dereferencing it `s->addTriangle...` is illegal.

Either initialize it with `new`, or don't use pointers at all - in this case you don't need pointers, just have

```
TriangleStrip s;
```

and

```
s.addTriangle(triangles[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever create a `TriangleStrip`.

This creates a **pointer** to a `TriangleStrip`.

```
TriangleStrip* s;
```

And this expects the pointer to be assigned to a `TriangleStrip`.  But that never happened.

```
s->addTriangle(triangles[i]);
```